# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL :glassfish server using netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

```
I am getting this error on using post method in my form-- HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL.
```

## My register.html file is as below:

```
    <html>        
    <head>        
    <title>Register form</title>        
    </head>        
    <body>        
    <form method="post" action="Register">        
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>        
    Email ID:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>        
    Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>        
    <input type="submit" value="register" />        
    </form>        
    </body>        
    </html>
```

### My Register.java servlet code is as below

```
package Glassfish;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Intel I 5
 */
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    try{

    //loading drivers for mysql
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//creating connection with the database 
      Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","user","pass");

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("insert into register values(?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, email);
    ps.setString(3, pass);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

      if(i>0)
      {
        out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
      }

    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

}

#### My Web.xml file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Glassfish.Register</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>

     </servlet-mapping>

     <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
 </web-app>
```

I have tried all instances provided in http error 405 for post methods in stack overflow but of no use.

Answer (score 1):

Change your public void service() method and instead change it to public void doGet() and remove the call doPost(req,resp) inside the method .Let me know if this helps. This will 100℅ work !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `doPost` method in your class, and handle POST requests in it.
You need also override `doGet` method, and provide a code to handle GET requests.
You shouldn't override `service` method (or at least in a way you have done it in your code). You are calling `doPost(request, response);` in your `service` method, that is borrowed from `HttpServlet` abstract class, and a default implementation of this method you can see here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#HttpServlet.doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29

```
351     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
352     throws ServletException, IOException
353     {
354     String protocol = req.getProtocol();
355     String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_post_not_supported");
356     if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
357         resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
358     } else {
359         resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
360     }
361     }
```

that is - it sends BAD_REQUEST or METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED errors to the browser.

Comment: if i add protected void do post (httpserverletrequest i get more errors in my whole java class file.. cud u suggest how to and where to safely add these codes in my java class.